# Crypography - submitting app

Tags: ios, app-store

First of all, I know this isn't the right forum for this kind of question and I will happily delete the question later but this is the only forum that I know I can find experienced and talented persons. I'm in the process of submitting an app to the App Store, and have to answer a question if my app is designed to use or incorporates cryptography.

My app relies heavily on custom models that derives from NSObject that are stored in an array, encoded to NSData which is then saved in NSUserDefaults.

Information gets saved using geofencing, the kind of information being saved are the time and location in the didEnter/ExitRegion methods. So my app uses location services, **and** CLGeocoder and MKLocalSearch. As well as **Apple's Reachability class**

I checked of "no" in the question and wrote the same description in my review notes but I'm still anxious for this and I was wondering if I had chosen correctly? I've read a variety of documents but I'm still not sure.

Thanks a lot people, I really need an answer to this!

Once again, thanks!

Comment: I believe is correct. I mark no with similar situation, cryptography (i think so)  is when use an algorithm not permitted for security reasons in some countries. If you use an special algorithm with 256 bits or something "weird" you must mark yes.

Comment: @Beto that was what I thought. I haven't done any explicit encryption, so the only thing I could imagine was NSUserDefaults / reachability class / location services / mklocalsearch. If more people could back this theory, that would be great!

Comment: of course, done so now:) @ PetahChristian

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NSUserDefaults, Core Location, MapKit, and Foundation objects such as NSData have nothing to do with encryption.

The information you've saved in NSUserDefaults has not been encrypted;  anyone can decode and read it.

If you had used some type of encryption algorithm that encodes plaintext into ciphertext, that would require a 'Yes' answer.

Comment: I see, so even if my app automatically saves information - no will be the correct answer? And you're completely sure?

Comment: There is a difference between saving information, and saving encrypted information.  Encryption is deliberate.  Don't confuse encryption with encoding (converting data to a format which can be saved).

Comment: Yeah, I know but I wasn't sure if the OS had some fancy feature to encrypt it :) but, everything cool with saving info automatically?

Comment: No one can say "Your app doesn't use encryption," because we haven't reviewed your source code.  If you know for certain that you didn't add any encryption, then you can be confident that your app is not designed to use or incorporate cryptography.  In other words, Apple isn't asking you to make a statement that their frameworks (such as Foundation or MapKit or CoreLocation) don't use encryption, they're asking you to make a statement about your code.  Don't overthink it.

Comment: I agree. I tend to always be overly anxious about things like this, but more confident now. Thanks for your help:)

Answer (score 2):

Just confirm your question.

If your cryptography is compatible with this [Apple Document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/SubmittingTheApp.html) (read the most important part above) and [this Government Document](http://www.bis.doc.gov/index.php/policy-guidance/encryption) you don't need mark YES.

**From Apple Documentation**

Cryptography and U.S. Export Compliance
U.S. export laws require that products containing encryption be properly authorized for export. When you’re ready to upload your first build for your app or upload a new build, iTunes Connect presents a series of questions regarding software encryption. The questions are designed to determine the level of encryption in the app according to U.S. Bureau of Industry and Security (BIS) classifications. Based on your answers, you may be required to provide one or more of the following documents:

Encryption Registration approval from BIS
CCATS approval from BIS
French import declaration
For more information on BIS requirements for encryption, go to Bureau of Industry and Security Encryption webpage.

All apps distributed through the App Store or Mac App Store must go through the encryption review: All apps are uploaded to an Apple server in the United States, which means that your product is exported from the United States and is captured by U.S. export laws. This requirement applies even if you plan to distribute apps only within your own country.

Important:  If your app requires that you provide additional documents for the encryption review, your app won’t have the Ready for Sale status on the store until Export Compliance has reviewed and approved your documents. The app can’t be distributed for prerelease testing by external testers until Export Compliance has reviewed and approved it.